# How to configure Transport Security with Client Certificate with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl, certificate

We'd like to configure Transport Security (SSL) with Client Certificate for our WCF Service (basicHttpBinding) which is used only by Company X as a client of our service.

From our side, we have 2 load-balanced servers and from their side there is only 1 server.

On the 3 servers just mentioned, we have installed the same Root Certificate Authority which would be used to issue other certificates.

There are lots of confusion on how to configure this with WCF and where to install which certificates?

1) How many other certificates we should be issuing and to be installed where?
Should Company X issue a certificate as well?
Which certificates should be installed on our 2 Servers and which ones on their Server?

We should be trusting their server so I'd guess we'd require them to install a Client Certificate, right? Who and from where this certificate will be issued?
From the service side, how to configure WCF to trust this client certificate when received?

They should be trusting our 2 servers, how does this work?

2) What is the purpose of

```
<serviceCertificate>
```

and should we adding it to our config? Should the Company X add it to their end?

I've read the purpose is "to authenticate/identify the service to the client". I'd guess this means that we only need to install these certificates on our servers and they shouldn't be installed on the client's server.

Does it mean that it is the same as ssl?

We have hosted the WCF Service on IIS and we have also configured SSL via IIS. Does it mean we don't have to add

```
<serviceCertificate>
```

on our WCF config then?

3)

```
<clientCertificate>
```

I've read the purpose is to identify the client to the service therefore I'd guess it's something that should be installed on the Client's Machine certainly.

Who will issue this certificate? The Root Certificate Authority on our servers or on theirs?

Should this certificate be installed on our both Servers as well? or just on their side?

From our service side, how are we going to trust this client certificate? Any web.config settings or?

Many thanks,